# Error when using CMake to compile CUDA project: "tuple ... error: wrong number of template arguments"

Tags: c++, cmake, libtorch

## Project Structure

Structure is listed below, where `_ext` serves as a library for `PointConv` project (root project) and is divided into `include` and `src` directories.
`libtorch` dirtory is pytorch library for C.

## CMakeLists.txt

```
| (root)
| main.cpp
| CMakeLists.txt
----| (_ext)
----| CMakeLists.txt
--------| (src)
--------| group_points_gpu.cu
--------| group_points.cpp
--------| CMakeLists.txt
--------| (include)
--------| group_points.h
----| (libtorch)
----| ...(emited)
```

Here's the CMakeLists.txt in root dir.

```
############ CMakeLists.txt in root dir ############
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.23.0)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc-7")    # compiler
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-7")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)                # standard
project (PointConv LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(PointConv main.cpp)

target_compile_features(PointConv PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(PointConv PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# include
include_directories("libtorch/include/")
include_directories("libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/")
include_directories("/data_HDD/zhuxingyu/anaconda3/envs/p11/include/python3.8/")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/_ext/include")
# subdir
add_subdirectory(_ext)
target_link_libraries(PointConv _ext)

file(GLOB LIBTORCH_LIBS "libtorch/lib/*.a" "libtorch/lib/*.so")
target_link_libraries(PointConv ${LIBTORCH_LIBS})
```

```
############ CMakeLists.txt in root/_ext/src dir ############
project(_ext CXX CUDA)

set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/cuda)
find_package(CUDA 11.4 REQUIRED)

file(GLOB CUDA_FILES "*.cu")
file(GLOB CXX_FILES "*.cpp")
# cmake will not comiple cu files without this statement
add_library(_ext ${CUDA_FILES} ${CXX_FILES})

target_compile_features(_ext PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(_ext PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

## cxx/cu file

```
### main.cpp ###
#include<stdio.h>
#include "group_points.h"

int main(){
    printf("1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
### group_points.h ###
#pragma once
#include <torch/extension.h>

at::Tensor group_points(at::Tensor points, at::Tensor idx);
at::Tensor group_points_grad(at::Tensor grad_out, at::Tensor idx, const int n);
```

## Error

Cmake works fine but I failded to compile main.cpp. In summary, this might be an issue of compatibility between g++ and pytorch. Here's part of the error log:

```
/data_HDD/zhuxingyu/vscode/meshwatermark/model/pointconv/libtorch/include/ATen/ExpandUtils.h:173:169:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:495:244: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 2)
       return  __and_<__not_<is_same<tuple<_Elements...>,
```

The rest of the error are following the saming pattern: `xxx: error: wrong number of template arguments (y, should be z)`.

## Analysis

As I said above, this might be a compability issue. I'm using libtorch of version 1.12.0 with cuda version 11.3. I have both g++ 6.5 and g++ 7.5 but it always includes `/usr/include/c++/6/tuple`. I dont know how to solve this problem without downgrading my pytorch and cuda.

Comment: You pretty good job of providing an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! Thanks for that. You should be able to select a compiler by setting the [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) variable. You can do this in the config command via [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D), or in a CMakePresets.json preset.

Comment: I think it might help to show more of the compiler error diagnostic message if there is more that you haven't shown. Also, what C++ language standard are you setting (Ex. via [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) or [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#high-level-meta-features-indicating-c-standard-support))?

Comment: @starball I've set both standard and compile as you suggested (and also updated above). But it didn't work. If you want to see full log text, I can show you in this link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/shK2zDX6Xk/, most of which are warnings, if you want to check errors, better search keyword "error", and most of the errors seems following the same pattern.

Comment: I would be looking to use a newer C++ compiler than gcc 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out to be an issue of NVCC <9.2. Fixed once use NVCC 11.4.**

There are two cuda version (VERSION 9.1, VERSION 11.4)on my system. `find_package(CUDA 11.4 REQUIRED)` does not let cmake use the compiler of nvcc@11.4. Instead, it uses nvcc@9.1, which causes the issue.

Should tell cmake which the prefered nvcc compiler path before `project` statement

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc) # path to nvcc 11.4
set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/cuda/)
```